# finding and moving files via grep, or awk?

Tags: bash, awk, grep

Is there a way to do the followings with either grep, or awk, and piping:

Consider a parent folder A, with four folders B, C, D, E in it. And unknown number of layers in each folder. I want to find .pdf files in the hierarchy of each folders B, C, D, E. This is simply can be done via find:

```
find . -type f -name "*.pdf"
```

Once files are found, I would move it to another folder. So, a .pdf file found under B will be moved to a newly created folder called B_NEW in the parent folder, and so on. I don't know how to take the pipe and create the folder and do the moving/copying!

Comment: batch using find on each file in folder (in temporary file), grep -c on list searching .pdf, if any, sed to generate a copy command of each  file  (adding a `cp`) and as destination with the same name but duplicating the 2 first level of the path via a quite easy  `s///`.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Makes sense but have no idea how to do it!

Comment: @user3639557 Where are you copying to ? Do you need to create the new directory structure in the script or does it already exist ?

Comment: @JID just updated the question.

Comment: @user3639557 Where is BB though ? in the same folder, how do you decide the names for the new folders ?

Comment: @JID added the clarification to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
TempList=/tmp/ListOfParentFile.tmp
ParentFolder=A
here="$( pwd )"

cd ${ParentFolder}/..
find ${ParentFolder##*/} -print > ${TempList}
if [ $( grep -c -E -e '.pdf$' ${TempList} ) -gt 0 ]
 then
   mkdir "${ParentFolder##*/}${ParentFolder##*/}"

   echo 'set -vx' > ${TempList}.action
   sed -n '\#^\([^/]*\)/\([^/]*\)$#  s##cp -fr &* \1\1/\2\2#p' ${TempList} >> ${TempList}.action
   . ${TempList}.action

   rm ${TempList}*
   cd ${here}
 fi
```

Quick and dirty for the concept, add any security on this. Tested in KSH/AIX

**Explaination**

- init some variable used later

  - Parent Folder to check (easy to put in a loop with this)
  - temporary file name
  - calling folder (we use a cd later for an easier use of result from Parent (call *Reference folder* here after) folder)
- go to Parent (upper) of Reference folder
- take all file inside the Reference folder (including subfolder) via find and put it in a temporary file
- grep the file to see if a pdf is inside (the sub process inside de if)
- if there is a pdf

  - create a folder (same level as Reference) with the *double* name of the reference folder  `${ParentFolder##*/}` twice. Using the shell feature to remove any part of the string before the last `/`
  - create a temporary *action* file with a set -vx to trace activity (the `set -vx` is optional, not the file)
  - using sed on the temporary file (first generate file with find) generate a set of action based on each line entry that are structured as `Reference/Subfolder` making a copy of folder and content recursively. Other line are discarded so only 1st level of subfolder in Reference folder are treated.
  - running the temporaty action file in current shell (batch in this case)
  - clean temporary file
  - going back to starting folder

Comment: Could you add an explanation please? I have no idea what half of this does but it looks interesting!

Comment: :-) some latency betwenn this comment and save of my edition of the reply

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
while read file;do
        dir="New_${file#*/}" #strip to first / and add "New_"
        dir="${dir%/*}" #strip off filename
        if [[ ! -d "$dir" ]];then #check directory exists or not
                echo "creating directory structure $dir"
                mkdir -p "$dir" || (echo "failed to create $dir.Aborting for this file" && continue) # make the directory and continue to next file if this fails
        fi
        echo "copying $file -> $dir/"
        cp "$file" "$dir/" || (echo "failed to copy $file.Aborting for this file" && continue) #Copy the file to newly created dir

done< <(find . -type f -name "*.pdf") #find the files
```

---

#### Test

```
$find . -type f -name "*.pdf"
./A/4.pdf
./A/3.pdf
./A/1.pdf
./A/2.pdf
./C/4.pdf
./C/3.pdf
./C/1.pdf
./C/2.pdf
./B/7.pdf
./B/8.pdf
./B/6.pdf
./B/5.pdf
./D/7.pdf
./D/8.pdf
./D/6.pdf
./D/5.pdf
```

.

```
$./Scipt
creating directory structure New_A
copying ./A/4.pdf -> New_A/
copying ./A/3.pdf -> New_A/
copying ./A/1.pdf -> New_A/
copying ./A/2.pdf -> New_A/
creating directory structure New_C
copying ./C/4.pdf -> New_C/
copying ./C/3.pdf -> New_C/
copying ./C/1.pdf -> New_C/
copying ./C/2.pdf -> New_C/
creating directory structure New_B
copying ./B/7.pdf -> New_B/
copying ./B/8.pdf -> New_B/
copying ./B/6.pdf -> New_B/
copying ./B/5.pdf -> New_B/
creating directory structure New_D
copying ./D/7.pdf -> New_D/
copying ./D/8.pdf -> New_D/
copying ./D/6.pdf -> New_D/
copying ./D/5.pdf -> New_D/
```

.

```
find . -type f -name "*.pdf"
./A/4.pdf
./A/3.pdf
./A/1.pdf
./A/2.pdf
./C/4.pdf
./C/3.pdf
./C/1.pdf
./C/2.pdf
./New_C/4.pdf
./New_C/3.pdf
./New_C/1.pdf
./New_C/2.pdf
./New_A/4.pdf
./New_A/3.pdf
./New_A/1.pdf
./New_A/2.pdf
./B/7.pdf
./B/8.pdf
./B/6.pdf
./B/5.pdf
./New_B/7.pdf
./New_B/8.pdf
./New_B/6.pdf
./New_B/5.pdf
./New_D/7.pdf
./New_D/8.pdf
./New_D/6.pdf
./New_D/5.pdf
./D/7.pdf
./D/8.pdf
./D/6.pdf
./D/5.pdf
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I get the following errors: 1) cp: cannot stat some-file-name 2) No such file or directory 3) cp: omitting directory

Comment: And you copied it exactly and you are using bash ? Do your folders/files have spaces in the names or newlines or weird stuff

Comment: Yes. I replace space, ., etc with underscore. For half of the folders it creates the new, for the remaining half it gives error.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand. Can you put examples of the folder names before and after in your question please ? With example of ones that give errors.

Comment: For example: cp: omitting directory ‘1’

Comment: Or: cp: cannot stat ‘Latest/History/EmilyDi.pdf’:

Comment: Does `Latest/History/EmilyDi.pdf` exist ? Please add the full paths to your question as i have no chance of helping with just these comments.]